# phonegap admob and network plugin says duplicate symbol

Tags: ios, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an iOS application with PhoneGap 4.0.0 and added these two plugins using *cordova plugin add* command:

```
org.apache.cordova.network-information
com.admob.google
```

When I exclude one of them from the project everything seems fine but when two plugins are included in the project it says

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVReachability
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVReachability

ld:2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: As claimed, the plugin com.admob.google add some feature to detect network, it may conflict with the apache network plugin.

You can try using another AdMob plugin: com.google.cordova.admob

Comment: Could you open the issue on [github admob cordova plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/issues)?